IF ISBLANK Excel Formula Assistance
I am trying to get a formula to work that uses IF(ISBLANK) and it's not working as I would expect.
My goal is to have this formula sum a group of rows, and if those rows are blank/null then populate data from a different reference cell. Otherwise, if not blank use the sum of the rows even if the total of the sum is 0.
Here is the formula I have currently, and it does a great job of returning 0
=IF(ISBLANK(SUM(B3:B6)),E1/12,SUM(B3:B6))
Simple Table Reference...
enter image description here
This works as expected if I don't use the sum function it appears but that doesn't accomplish what I am looking for unfortunately.
Works
=IF(ISBLANK(B3),E1/12,SUM(B3:B6))
Any recommendations on a better way to accomplish this?

So, do you want the decision based on whether the ENTIRE RANGE is empty?  Wouldn't checking for a SUM of 0 be enough?

I believe what you are looking for is SUMIF or SUMIFS

What is in B3?  Is it a formula?

What if some values B3:B6 are blank and some are non-zero or numeric zero? Is one non-blank enough to want to know the sum rather than the alternative answer?

ISBLANK test if a cell is truly blank not if a formula does not return anything.  So it will return FALSE if there is a formula in that cell that returns an empty string ""
You want to test if the sum returns 0 or not, as SUM will not return a blank.
=IF(B3="",E1/12,SUM(B3:B6))


Sorry for the delay, I have been away from my computer for a while. To provide a little more details about this. What I am using this for is a forecasting tool. Each month I will use the original budget (which is the E1/12 in my example) until I bring in the actuals for the month. So each line item in B3:B6 in the example will have a unique value. Until I bring in actuals those fields will all be blank. I probably can only reference the top cell (B3) to make this work I suppose.
